# rviz_imu_plugin/imu failed to load

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, husky, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make the husky robot automatically explore a map with the explore_lite package.  I use melodic on 18.04 and the melodic-devel branches of each package.  In new terminals, running source ~/husky_ws/devel/setup.bash in each, I command:

```
roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
```

and encounter the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1593994893.360426019, 1308.840000000]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'rviz_imu_plugin/Imu' failed to load.  Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin rviz_imu_plugin/Imu. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
```

I did also clone the package https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools in my /src. I didn't change the contents of the package_description.xml, which reads:

```
<library path="lib/librviz_imu_plugin">

  <class name="rviz_imu_plugin/Imu"
         type="rviz::ImuDisplay"
         base_class_type="rviz::Display">

    <description>
      Displays the orientation and acceleration components of sensor_msgs/Imu messages.
    </description>

  </class>

</library>
```

Any advice about changing the xml of file layout is appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356474/rviz_imu_plugin/imu-failed-to-load/) by [ildaniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55506/ildaniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ildaniel,

You are missing a plugin. Just execute the following:

-

> sudo apt-get install ros-$(rosversion
> -d)-rviz-imu-plugin

Hope it works.

---

Originally posted by [syncware](https://answers.ros.org/users/71706/syncware/) with karma: 16 on 2021-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-25**:
With lack of response from the original poster, I marked this as an answer, not because this seems a solution but because this might likely resolve the issue. From the OP's description, we can only tell that `pluginlib` was told to find `rviz_imu_plugin/IMU` plugin but couldn't find, which doesn't directly mean .deb package was not installed. But it's likely.

Comment: I faced the same problem with Husky, and the suggested solution works. Thank you!